# Postfix notation stack C++

Tags: c++, stack

I am new to C++ and I want to use a stack to evaluate an expression given as an input (2+3*5+4 for example), containing only numbers, + and *. I wrote this code but it gives me Segmentation fault: 11. Could you please help me solve this or give me a hint about what could be wrong? Thank you! (I noticed there were similar questions on this site, but I couldn't use them to solve my problem)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

bool highPrecedence(char a, char b){
    if((a=='+')&&(b=='*'))
        return true;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    char c = 'a';
    double x;
    stack<char> stack;
    double v[10];
    int i=0;
    double res;
    while(true)
    {
        c = cin.get();

        if(c=='\n'){
            while(stack.size()!=0){
                if (stack.top()=='*'){
                    double res = v[i]*v[i-1];
                    i--;
                    v[i]=res;
                    stack.pop();
                }
                if (stack.top()=='+'){
                    res = v[i]+v[i-1];
                    i--;
                    v[i]=res;
                    stack.pop();

                }
            }
            break;
        }

        if ( '0'<=c && c<='9' )
        {
            cin.putback(c);
            cin>>x;
            cout<<"Operand "<<x<<endl;
            i=i+1;
            v[i]=x;
        }
        else
        {
            if(c!=' ') cout<< "Operator " <<c<<endl;
            if (stack.size()==0)
                stack.push(c);
            else{
                while((!highPrecedence(stack.top(),c)) && (stack.size()!=0)){
                    if (stack.top()=='*'){
                        double res = v[i]*v[i-1];
                        i--;
                        v[i]=res;
                        stack.pop();
                    }
                    if (stack.top()=='+'){
                        res = v[i]+v[i-1];
                        i--;
                        v[i]=res;
                        stack.pop();

                        }
                    }

                stack.push(c);
                }
            }

        }


    cout<<v[0]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of all your code. The linked page contains help on how to create one.

Comment: @MikeCAT ummm not sure. I use Xcode and terminal

Comment: `2+3*5+4 ` - This is infix notation - not postfix - look into reverse polish

Comment: @EdHeal yes I have it initially in infix, i need to convert to postfix and then evaluate it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501175/convert-infix-to-rpn-shunting-yard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using `stack.top()` is illegal if the `stack` is empty.
  Change `while((!highPrecedence(stack.top(),c)) && (stack.size()!=0)){`
  to `while((!stack.empty()) && (!highPrecedence(stack.top(),c))){`
- The initiali value of `i` is not good and you are printing uninitialized variable, which has indeterminate value.
  Change `int i=0;` to `int i=-1;`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked!